# What do these effects on units in the overworld mean?

Tags: pit-people

When exploring the overworld, some of the enemy units will appear with a sweaty or fiery animation. What do these effects means, and what causes them to appear over the enemy units?

Sweaty unit shown to the right of the caravan.
[image: sweating unit]

Fiery unit just below the caravan here.
[image: red unit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the skulls usually mean the group has spotted you and will try to come in your direction to fight. However, they move slow and you can easily run away or stun them with the cannon.

The fiery enemies are [elite enemies](http://pitpeople.gamepedia.com/Elite). They are usually harder/bigger groups of enemies to fight and provide a much tougher challenge. Things worth noting about elites; you get an achievement for the first group you beat of them, and if you capture any of them, they do not retain elite or buffed status when in your house.

The sweaty icon (water drop), while I have not seen how it alters combat vs those groups, I know that that icon usually means missing/low accuracy during combat, so it may have to do with it being a pixie (ranged character) having lower accuracy for when you get into battle. Not sure why, but there is not much information about the overworld stuff whether it's through wikis or threads etc.

Comment: Additionally, elite units don't seem to get stunned with the cannon and charge more directly at you when you're close by, and the sweating units seem to try avoiding you as you get close.